# Writing the results of a function to a file in Python 2.7

Tags: python, function, file, python-2.7, file-io

I'm trying to write the results of a function to a file;
In the code below, the results do not get saved to the output file (it writes:"None"):

```
def program():
    print "Hello World!"


with open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(str(program()))
```

The goal is to write the entire output of my script (not shown here) to a file from within the script; I'm guessing there's a better way to do this (stdout?) but I'm a beginner with little knowledge ;-)

I've tried a few workarounds with the same result, I've search for an answer but couldn't find this exact question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: change `print` in the function to `return`

Comment: That is because program *prints* "Hello World!", it doesn't *return* it.  You are trying to save the return value, which is `None`

Comment: Yep, that worked, many thanks!  Now I'll see if I can implement this to my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `return` instead of printing:

```
def program():
    return "Hello World!"
```

Without `return`, the function `program` will return `None` value.